# Getting date difference between consecutive rows in the same group

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a database with the following data:

```
Group      ID      Time
1          1       16:00:00
1          2       16:02:00
1          3       16:03:00
2          4       16:09:00
2          5       16:10:00
2          6       16:14:00
```

I am trying to find the difference in times between the consecutive rows within each group. Using `LAG()` and `DATEDIFF()` (ie. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43055820), right now I have the following result set:

```
Group      ID       Difference
    1          1    NULL
    1          2    00:02:00
    1          3    00:01:00
    2          4    00:06:00
    2          5    00:01:00
    2          6    00:04:00
```

However I need the difference to reset when a new group is reached, as in below. Can anyone advise?

```
Group      ID       Difference
    1          1    NULL
    1          2    00:02:00
    1          3    00:01:00
    2          4    NULL
    2          5    00:01:00
    2          6    00:04:00
```

Comment: Edit your question and include your query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code would look something like:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(second, lag(time) over (partition by group order by id), time)
from t;
```

This returns the difference as a number of seconds, but you seem to know how to convert that to a time representation.  You also seem to know that `group` is not acceptable as a column name, because it is a SQL keyword.

Based on the question, you have put `group` in the `order by` clause of the `lag()`, not the `partition by`.