# mysql group by uid to calculate consecutive date diff

Tags: mysql

**data**

```
uid  data_date 
a    2020-12-31
a    2021-01-01
a    2021-01-05
b    2021-03-02
b    2021-03-05
b    2021-03-07
```

**Expected**

```
uid  date_diff
a    1
a    4
b    3
b    2
```

**Try and Ref**

- [Getting date difference between consecutive rows in the same group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745548/getting-date-difference-between-consecutive-rows-in-the-same-group). I could not use any windows function because of mysql version.

mysql version: 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can try using `LAG` along with `DATEDIFF`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(data_date) OVER (PARTITION BY uid
                                   ORDER BY data_date) AS lag_data_date
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT uid, DATEDIFF(data_date, lag_data_date) AS date_diff
FROM cte
WHERE lag_data_date IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY uid, data_date;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The `HAVING` clause above filters off the "first" record for each `uid` group, as that first record technically doesn't have any date diff associated with it (nor does your expected output contain this record).

**Edit:**

Here is a version which should run on MySQL 5.7 or earlier.  It uses a correlated subquery instead of `LAG()`, to find the lag date:

```sql
SELECT uid,
    DATEDIFF(data_date,
        (SELECT t2.data_date FROM yourTable t2
         WHERE t2.uid = t1.uid AND t2.data_date < t1.data_date
         ORDER BY t2.data_date DESC LIMIT 1)) AS date_diff
FROM yourTable t1
HAVING date_diff IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY uid, data_date;
```

### Demo

Comment: how about mysql  5.5

Comment: @Jack Check the updated answer for a MySQL 5.5 compatible version.  For future reference, if you're using a MySQL version earlier than 8+, you should probably state that, as earlier versions are on the way out, and may not even be supported for much longer.