# Is it possible to get time difference between dates and provide a default value, with PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

So, the table setup is something like this:

```
table: ticket(ticket_id, ...)

table: ticket_status_history(status_history_id, ticket_id, ticket_status, ticket_status_datetime)
```

The default ticket_status is `OPEN`, and the first ticket status that I'm interested in is `ACKNOWLEDGED`.

So, the idea is that a specific ticket has a set of `ticket_status_history` events, each recorded in the separate table. Each ticket status entry points to its corresponding ticket, ticket_id is a foreign key.

Now, a ticket can actually be created directly in `ACKNOWLEDGED` so it would get a corresponding entry directly in `ACKNOWLEDGED`, without ever being in `OPEN`. But many of them will go `OPEN` -> `ACKNOWLEDGED` -> ...

What I'd like to do would be to determine for each ticket the time interval between ticket creation (`OPEN`) and ticket acknowledgment (`ACKNOWLEDGE`), but if the state is directly `ACKNOWLEDGE`, set the time difference as a default of 0 (because the ticket was created directly in this state).

Is this doable in SQL, for PostgreSQL? I'm a bit stumped at the moment. I found this: [Calculate Time Difference Between Two Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2357515/1320143) but it's for SQL Server, instead, plus I'm not sure how the default value could be included.

The end state would actually be aggregating the time differences and computing an average duration, but I can't figure out the first step

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query could look like this:

```
SELECT t.*,coalesce(ack.ticket_status_datetime - op.ticket_status_datetime 
                    ,'0'::interval) AS op_ack_diff
FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN ticket_status_history ack ON(t.ticket_id = ack.ticket_id
                                       AND ack.ticket_status = 'ACKNOWLEDGED')
LEFT JOIN  ticket_status_history op ON(t.ticket_id = op.ticket_id
                                       AND op.ticket_status = 'OPENED')
WHERE t.ticket_id = x;
```

The difference of the timestamps yields null if one of the entries is missing. The coalesce function will return its second argument in this case.

Comment: Great answer. The thing is, if ACK is null but OP is not, the correct difference would be `current_time` - OP, since technically the ticket isn't yet in ACK. I wonder how this can be handled? Because 0 would be a lie :)

Comment: Found it, I can use `case` instead of coalesce, have more control with that. But your approach was the base for the solution, thanks a lot!

Comment: Replace ACK time with current_time if it is null: `coalesce(coalesce(ack.ticket_status_datetime,current_time) - op.ticket_status_datetime,0::interval)`